# How do I set the LRECL in C#.NET?

Tags: c#, ftp

I have been trying to ftp a dtl file from .net to, what I beleive, is an AS400. The error being reported back to me is: "One or more lines have been truncated" and the admin is saying the file is coming over with 256 lines that have variable length columns. I found this explanation online:

we have to establish defaults because no specifics about the file exist. The default RECFM is V and LRECL is 256. This means that SAS will scan the input record looking for the CR & LF to tell us that we are at the EOR. If the marker isn't found within the limit of the LRECL, SAS discards the data from the LRECL value to the end of the record and adds a message to the Log that "One or more lines have been truncated".

So I need to set the LRECL. How do I do this in C# .NET?

```
            FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpfullpath);
            ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pwd);

            ftp.KeepAlive = false;
            ftp.UseBinary = false;  
            ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(inputfilepath + ftpfileName);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            fs.Close();

            Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();

            int i = 0;
            int intBlock = 1786;
            int intBuffLeft = buffer.Length;

            while (i < buffer.Length)
            {
                if (intBuffLeft >= 1786)
                {
                    ftpstream.Write(buffer, i, intBlock);
                }
                else
                {
                    ftpstream.Write(buffer, i, intBuffLeft);
                }
                i += intBlock;
                intBuffLeft -= 1786;
            }
           ftpstream.Close();
```

Comment: Are you using ftpwebrequestto perform your transfer? Have you set it to transfer as binary or text? Do you have any code to show us?

Answer (score 0):

1786 isn't divisible by 256.

I didn't think that you needed to split stream contents up with ftpWebRequest.

Have you tried

```
StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(fileName);
byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
sourceStream.Close();

ftp.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
ftpstream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
ftpstream.Close();
```